Raster Calculator in QGIS 3.40 results into two satellite images side by side
I am currently working on two Sentinel-2 images. I want to use the downloaded images to calculate the NDBI.
Initially, I mosaicked the Bands 8 (NIR) and 11 (SWIR) of the two different Sentinel-2 images and extracted my area of interest.
Then in QGIS, I used the Raster Calculator tool to compute the NDBI using the formula (B11-B8) / (B11+B8). It resulted in 1 and -1 values, but the image seems unusual as it generated the combination of the two raster datasets side by side, not the actual NDBI results.
Any reason/s why this is occurring?

